# PHP sql insert code is returning false even when sql command if correct and database is too

Tags: php, mysql

Once again I come back to all of you with another question.

I have tried everything in my mind as well as most of the recommendations I have found on the web and here in Stackoverflow but nothing seems to fix this issue for me.

For some reason the sql command in my code is returning false even though it should not.

Here is my php file called (dbRKS-DBTest.php)

```
<?php
//Gets server connection credentials stored in serConCred.php
//require_once('/../prctrc/servConCred2.php');
require_once('C:\wamp64.2\www\servConCred2.php');

//SQL code for connection w/ error control
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if(!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Selection of the databse w/ error control
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($con, DB_NAME);

if(!$db_selected){
die('Can not use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

//VARIABLES & CONSTANTS

//Principal Investigator Information 
$PI_Selected = '6';

//Regulatory Knowledge and Support Core Requests variables
$RKS_REQ_1_Develop = '1';


//This sets a starting point in the rollback process in case of errors along the code
$success = true; //Flag to determine success of transaction
//start transaction
$command = "SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $command);
$command = "BEGIN";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $command);


//Delete this portion of code afyer testing is finished
//Core Requests saved to database
$sql = "INSERT INTO rpgp_form_table_3 (idPI, RKS_REQ_1_Develop) 
                    VALUES ('$PI_Selected', '$RKS_REQ_1_Develop')";  

//*************TEsts code for "SCOPE_IDENTITY()" -> insert_id() for mysql
$sqlInsertId = mysqli_insert_id($con); //This value is supposed to be 0 since no queries have been executed.
echo "<br>MYSQLi_INSERT_ID() value before query should be 0 and it is:= " . $sqlInsertId;

//Checks for errors in the db connection.   
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); //Executes query.

if($result == false){ //Checks to see for errors in previews query ($sql)
    //die ('<br>Error in query to Main Form: Research Proposal Grant Preparation: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    echo "<br>Result for the sql run returned FALSE. Check for error in sql code execution.";
    echo "<br>Error given by php is: " . mysqli_error($con);

    $success = false; //Chances success to false is it encounted an error in order to rollback transaction to database
}
else{

//*************TEsts code for "SCOPE_IDENTITY()" -> insert_id() for mysql
$sqlInsertId = mysqli_insert_id($con); //Saves the last id entered. This would be for the main table
echo "<br>MYSQLi_INSERT_ID() value after Main form query= " . $sqlInsertId; //Displays id last stored. This is the main forms id
$MAIN_ID = mysqli_insert_id($con);  //Sets last entered id in the MAIN Form db to variable  
}   


 //Checks for errors or craches inside the code
 // If found, execute rollback
 if($success){
     $command = "COMMIT";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $command);
     echo "<br>Tables have been saved witn 0 errors.";

 }
 else{
     $command = "ROLLBACK";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $command);
     echo "<br>Error! Databases could not be saved. <br>
     We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause. <br> 
     Please contact a system administrator at PRCTRC.";
 }
 $command = "SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1"; //return to autocommit
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $command);



//Displays message 
//echo '<br>Connection Successfully. ';
//echo '<br>Database have been saved';

//Close the sql connection to dababase
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is my php frontend html code named (RPGPHomeQueryTest.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<form id="testQuery" name="testQuery" method="post" action="../dbRKS-DBTest.php" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit" value="Submit query"/>
</form>
</html>
```

And here is how my database looks (rpgp_form_table_3):

[image]

---

So, when I open my html code, All I will see is a button since its all the code there is there. Once you press the button, the form should submit and execute the php code called (dbRKS-DBTest.php). This should take the predetermine values I already declared and saved them to the database called (rpgp_form_table_3). This database is set to InnoDB format.

Now, the output I should be getting is a message saying "Tables have been saved witn 0 errors." but the problem is that the message I am getting is this one bolow:

[image]

I honestly don't know why. I am posting this message to find guidance to this issue. I am still learning by myself and its been very did-heartedly to not find a solution this fixing this.

As always, I thank you for your patient and guidance! Let me know what other details I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the SQL code you run:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO rpgp_form_table_3 (idPI, RKS_REQ_1_Develop) 
                VALUES ('$PI_Selected', '$RKS_REQ_1_Develop')";
```

You are inserting data into `rpgp_form_table_3`. From the screenshot, we can see that table has several (7) fields yet you are only inserting 2 fields. The question then is: do you need to specify a value for all fields?

The error you are getting states

> Error given by php is: Field 'idCollaRecord_1' doesn't have a default value Error! Databases could not be saved.

It's clear that you have to insert the row by specifying a value for each column, not just the two columns you are interested in.

Try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO rpgp_form_table_3 (idPl, RKS_REQ_1_Develop, idCollaRecord_1, idCollaRecord_2, idCollaRecord_3, idCollaRecord_4) 
                VALUES ('$PI_Selected', '$RKS_REQ_1_Develop',0,0,0,0)";
```

Comment: Hi there David. Thank you for your response. As I understand, when inserting values to a sql table, you don't need to specify all values that are going to be inserted to the database since I am defining which calumns I want to fill with what. Then again I tested your advice just in case and it still didn't work. :,(

Comment: You are right: in SQL you may (note the may) not need to provide in all the values. It depends on your schema.

Comment: After carefully thinking about it, I notice that I didn't define every table in my db as you said @David. When I did defined them all, it fixed the issue my friend. I thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Try this insert code. If the PI_Selected is NUMERIC use the First one. If it is string use the second one

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO rpgp_form_table_3 (idPI, RKS_REQ_1_Develop) VALUES (" . 
    $PI_Selected . ",'" . $RKS_REQ_1_Develop . "')";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO rpgp_form_table_3 (idPI, RKS_REQ_1_Develop) VALUES ('" . 
    $PI_Selected . "','" . $RKS_REQ_1_Develop . "')";
```